# Raspberry Pi Zero HDMI socket - available current?

Tags: raspberry-pi, identification, current-limiting

I have an ongoing [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45001/how-much-current-can-i-draw-from-each-models-hdmi-socket) on the [Raspberry Pi SE site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), in which I'm attempting to figure out how much current is available to devices connected to the HDMI socket of each Pi model. I *think* I've [figured out](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51177/32756) every model aside from the Pi Zero.

There are no schematics available for the Zero but, following some extreme squinting, I think that the most likely candidate for HDMI power management is the component labelled D6. It's immediately below the white printed 'HDMI' label to the right of the mini HDMI socket, which is towards the bottom left corner of the board.

[image: Raspberry Pi Zero]

The part is marked 'F03 | CD'. Some stumbling in the dark on Google turned up the [Diodes Incorporated DFLS130LQ / '1.0A SURFACE MOUNT SCHOTTKY BARRIER RECTIFIER'](http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/DFLS130LQ.pdf), which has identical markings.

Is it plausible that this part might limit current to pin 18 of the mini HDMI socket? If so, what is the maximum current that it would allow to pass?

Comment: You might want to read up about on what diodes are and what they do...

Comment: I claim zero experience, hence the question here. If all I get is mass facepalming at least I've ruled something out.

Comment: Without a schematic, it's pointless to speculate. But in any case, if you don't have enough electronics experience to know what a diode does, what exactly is it you're trying to do with the port that requires you to know the current?

Comment: It's common to use bus powered HDMI to VGA adapters such as [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Tendak-Gold-Plated-Adapter-Converter-Projector/dp/B00VTJVJ3S/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1468498736&sr=1-2&keywords=tendak+hdmi+vga) to provide a cleaner audio output than the Pi's 3.5mm jack, which is garbage. They often don't work as the Pi can't supply enough power through the HDMI connector. It would be useful to know what the limits are.

Comment: @goobering: Usually on this site we expect people to research a bit of the basics first and then ask questions where they are stuck.

Comment: Why via HDMI ? There are audio DAC boards/adapters that work with the RPi, even a USB soundcard should work. Connect that via a (powered) USB hub and all your concerns regarding power are gone because the audio device will be powered from the hub.

Comment: And even if you knew how much current the RPi zero can deliver, you also need to know how much current the HDMI to audio adapter needs.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, we do the same on the Pi board. From [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Screens): '200mA is the limit for the BAT54 diode (D1) on the board'. From [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=9819): 'BAT54 diode D1 which has a max current rating of 200 mA'. From [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=9819): 'there is also a diode in-between the PI and the HDMI output to prevent the HDMI device from attempting to power the PI, and that diode is rated just 200mA'. Each referenced from my question on the Pi board.

Comment: @FakeMoustache The DAC boards are expensive (circa 6X) compared to the HDMI boards, and they occupy GPIO pins which are often needed for other things.

Comment: @goobering: As I said, you might want to read about what a diode is. Hint: It does not regulate current.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I have limited experience. Mouser tells me they can: http://www.mouser.co.uk/Semiconductors/Discrete-Semiconductors/Diodes-Rectifiers/Current-Regulator-Diodes/_/N-ax1ml .

Comment: @goobering: If you spent reading a few seconds about them on e.g. wikipedia you would have noticed that CRDs are actually not diodes but FETs.

Comment: Oh, you want cheap ? Then use a USB sound card/stick, like: http://www.ebay.com/itm/PC-Desktop-Windows-USB-2-0-3D-Virtual-7-1-Channel-Audio-Sound-Card-Adapter-/221707492354?hash=item339ecbdc02:g:gxgAAOSweW5U9n4E 6x less expensive than the HDMI thingy.

Comment: @FakeMoustache The Pi A+ only has two USB sockets. It gets busy.

Comment: Those who name these "*current limiting* diodes" "diodes" expose  themselves as not having a clue about **proper** diodes. Naming these CRDs "diodes" is silly in my opinion.

Comment: Like I said: **connect it via a (powered) USB hub**. Problem solved.

Comment: I wouldn't argue otherwise, but as a novice I'm inclined to believe the naming schema of gigantic global electronics distributors.

Comment: Now you learned that even these distris often don't have a clue about the stuff they're selling. And they can't, they're sellers, not EEs. It's OK, as long as you always read the datasheet (for which a link is conveniently supplied).

Comment: @FakeMoustache Among the benefits of the smaller boards such as the Pi A+ is a small footprint. If I add a powered hub I have to incorporate an extra power supply, the often irritatingly perpendicular USB connectors, and I have to allow for people creating voltage differences by plugging the Pi and the hub into the wrong sockets. They're not ideal for many applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the current limit is not documented, then the only way to determine it is empirically. Get yourself a variable load and plot the voltage-vs-current curve for the HDMI power terminal.

Assuming the circuitry is sophisticated enough to protect itself from overload, you'll find the current limit directly. The shape of the curve will give you some idea of how the current limit is implemented.

Otherwise, you'll reach the dissipation limit of some component on the RPi board, and this will determine the current limit. A thermal imager would be one way to monitor for "hot spots".